# using javascript array method to print the value of x

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement, console.log

Could someone explain following code to me and what happens in `x.join = x.shift;`?

```js
x = [5, 10, 15];

x.join = x.shift;

if (x == 5 && x == 10 && x == 15)
  console.log('good');
```

Comment: We're gonna need to see all the code to understand what's going on here.  Do you mean the methods shift and join?

Comment: Yes the method , =>  x.join = x.shift; what happen in first time x.join and x.shift

Comment: don't do this, it makes no sense

Answer (score 2):

When you are doing the x== it calls toString. They replace join() with shift() which pulls off the first index.

```js
x = [5, 10, 15];

console.log(x.toString())

x.join = x.shift;

console.log(x.toString())
console.log(x.toString())
console.log(x.toString())
```

Please do not do this....

Answer (score 0):

First, the array function `shift` removes the first element of an array and returns it. So, for example:

```
x = [5, 10, 15]
a = x.shift() #now a = 5 and x = [10, 15]
```

Next, the line `x.join = x.shift` in your code basically reassigns your array's (`x`'s) `join` method to call `shift` instead of `join`. And as `join` is (apparently ?) used in `==`, then at each comparison, x's `shift()` method is called and returns the first available element.

So your code is equivalent to:

```js
x = [5, 10, 15];

if (x.shift() == 5 && x.shift() == 10 && x.shift() == 15)
  console.log('good');
```

Which is just an overkill way to check the array's first, second and third values against the values 5, 10, and 15.